# Setting up second router to assign first router ip addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, synology

First Router = RT2600ac Synology.
Lan Address: 192.168.0.1
Starting Address: 192.168.0.2
Ending Address: 192.168.0.254

The second Router = Google WiFi
Lan Address: 192.168.1.1
Staring Address: 192.168.1.2
Ending Address: 192.168.1.254

Query: Is it possible to have my google wifi to assign ip addresses from the first router?

Example: If I try to connect to the google wifi; it would assign the ip address of 192.168.0.x instead of 192.168.1.x.

Diagram: https://snipboard.io/HXdnTR.jpg

The reason I want it to get assigned to the .0.x because I wanted to manipulate the device and also monitor it. I’m trying to cut cost so I don’t have to buy the synology mesh routers. If I can get google wifi to act as a mesh, it would save me a tons. It’s working great so far, but the issue is, I’m not seeing the device in the traffic logs. However when I manually assign the ip address from the device; I can control it. Manually setup ip is easy but kids know how to set it dhcp and would get free internet time when they’re suppose to do their homework.

Comment: Please include a network diagram (how are these devices connected to each other, and to the Internet?  Please include in the diagram at least one machine that you would want to be assigned a 192.168.0.x IP address by the Google WiFi device).  Also, a fundamental question: "Why?"  What do you hope to gain by such a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Set the second router into bridge mode (AP bridged with WAN), connect WAN on second router with LAN on first router. Disable all services on the second router.

Then the services on the first router (in particular DHCP) will control everything on the second router WAN. In particular, it will give out `192.168.0.*` addresses.

If your second router doesn't support bridge mode, you need to install some firmware on it (e.g. OpenWRT, check if your hardware is supported) that does.

Comment: Google router can do bridge mode only if it’s not set as access point or mesh. I have 6 of them so that method wont work.

Comment: This is an interesting setup, because normally bridge mode can **only** be done with an AP (because WLAN frames use 3-address mode by default, so it works neither as a WLAN client, nor as a mesh). So Google likely means something else by "bridge mode", and probably calls bridging the AP to WAN (which is what you need to do) again something else.